# Can’t reinstall Mac OS el capital because Recovery HD disk is locked. Anyone know how to bypass this?

Tags: macos, recovery-hd

I'm trying to reinstall Mac OS X El Capitan on my 2009 MacBook pro. Disk Utility lists a single SSD with a capacity of 250.06GB and a single partition (OS X Base system) that is taking up 249.85GB. When I try to create another partition it says that I need to enable journaling, but the option is greyed out. I also can't reinstall from the internet because the OS X Base System partition is locked.

Comment: The base system should be locked. It’s a virtual mount. Are you looking for Apple instructions how to erase your drive so you can install the OS?

Comment: I’m just trying to get my Mac working. I’ve tried erasing but I keep getting errors and nothing goes past that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any data that you would like to keep? If not, then I would recommend erasing everything and resintalling macOS from Internet Recovery. If not, then try running First Aid. If none of these work, use `fsck` from Single-User Mode.

Comment: I don’t mind losing my stuff. Tried First Aid but it didn’t work. Please explain how to get to Single-User Mode so that I can use fsck

Comment: Reboot your computer and press Command + S while its starting up. If you don't mind losing anything, I would strongly recommend erasing everything. If nothing works, then you can try using a bootable USB installer. Check this out: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Answer (score 0):

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496

Above is A step by step guide to erase and install your Mac. Be sure you erase your drive, all partitions completely.

It may go faster than the pro since you may be able to use Recovery HD based on your locked base system being present already.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387892/5472

A fully locked drive can be a symptom of hardware failure, so I would try to connect the Mac to another in target mode and erase the problem drive to be sure it’s hardware failure before paying for a repair.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac

It has links on repair you can try.

Comment: I’ve tried all these but nothing seems to work

Comment: If you can’t erase your hard drive from recovery, it’s time to replace that drive or the logic board. Usually people don’t follow the steps precisely, but it’s possible your system has failed. Especially if you have followed both articles completely and in order.

Comment: @bmike Comparing sizes, the disk appears to harbor two partitions: 1. EFI (210 MB) **and** 2. a **giant** recovery partition (or more precisely: the content of the BaseSystem.dmg) (249.85 GB). The OP won't be allowed to erase the disk the Mac boots from.

Comment: Whichever commands I use to boot up all lead to the OS X Utilities window (even trying to boot in safe mode still leads to the same).  From there if I try to reinstall OS X I can’t because the Recovery HD is locked. What could be the issue?

Comment: Erase the drive, make it’s name new. What error do you get using disk utility before you attempt another install, @goatN ?

Comment: The erasing has failed. Getting a ‘Erase process has failed, couldn’t unmount disk’ error

Comment: Bunker @goatN  I’ve has some luck getting the unmount to work in target disk mode. Then the erase succeeds. If not, replace the drive and or cable or controller.

Comment: For some reason it’s managed to erase and I’ve created new partitions. However when trying to reinstall, I’m prompted to log into Apple store and after doing that the process fails due to a ‘This item is temporarily unavailable, Please try again later’ error. 

Is there any way to reinstall offline without internet/Apple store?

Comment: No, these instructions assume unfettered network access to check signatures and download drivers and firmware to slipstream into the installer if needed.

Comment: Sooooo...that’s it? Nothing more I can do?

Comment: Connect to the internet? This is what unfettered access means. See the 17.0.0.0 network section in requirements. https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/guide/apple-configurator-2/apdebea5be51/mac You could also hire someone that can troubleshoot this or do the install.

Comment: I’m connected to the internet! Forgot to mention that. 
I’ll keep trying, maybe get a faster connection. If all else fails then I’ll get someone to install it for me. 
Thanks for the follow up updates

Comment: Not sure,, but this one is fighting you. Maybe put up an answer how you got past the lock.

Comment: I restarted again in recovery mode and tried it again and voila!

Answer (score 0):

"OS X Base System" is the name for the OS installer disk. It sounds like your entire SSD has been wiped and turned into an OS X installer. So you're booting to the SSD, and bringing up the OS X installer, but you've got nowhere else to install it to, and it can't install over itself.

If Internet Recovery doesn't work, then I would get an external drive. Then you can install OS X onto that, then boot from there and sort out your internal.

Comment: Do you mean I download OS El Capitan and save it on a flash drive then use this to boot my Mac?

Comment: Your entire internal SSD has been turned into an installer disk. You don't need to download another installer: you need a disk to install it on. You can't use the SSD because you're already using that.

Comment: I’ve tried reinstalling with an external drive but failed since it’s attempting to install from Apple store. Is there an option which involves doing it without internet?

Comment: You can try booting into macOS Recovery then creating a new APFS partition for macOS.